# Am getting error as "Expression must have (pointer-to-)function type" in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Hi i have the below code

```
# include <iostream>
# include <limits>
# include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class fahrenheit
{
    float f,c,x;
public:
    void getdata();
    void display();
}

void fahrenheit::getdata()
{
    cout << "Enter the value of f : ";
    cin >> f;
    x=f-32;
    c=5/9(x);   //Here i am getting error as Expression must have (pointer-to-)function type //
}

void fahrenheit::display()
{
    cout << "c=" << c;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();

}

int main()
{
    fahrenheit f;
    f.getdata();
    f.display();
}
```

i have given the datatype as float for the input variables , but i am not sure what should be done to rectify the error .

Answer (score 3):

`5/9(x)` doesn't remotely look like C++. You likely meant `c = 5.0 / 9.0 * x;`

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you forgot about a semicolon right after the class definition.
Second, I presume you wanted to multiply x by 9. Write
        c=5/9*(x)

otherwise the compiler tries to find a function called `9(int x)` (which is an incorrect name for a function anyway) and realizes that 9 is in no sense any function pointer but just an `int`.. that's what the error means.

By the way.. if you write 5/9 compiler understands it as int values being divided.
It will divide int(5) by 9 using an int `/` operator, which after dividing will return
`floor(5/9) = 0` . If you want to have a `float` or `double` division you have to inform the compiler that your values are floats(doubles).

For doubles: `5.0/9.0*x`
For floats: `5.0f/9.0f * x`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the multiplication operator `*`.

```
c=5/9*(x);
```

Comment: operator is the better term ;)

Comment: This would make `c == 0` for any value of `x`.